# Mysql select rows not in table error

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema:

```
product: id , title
client: id, name
client_has_product:id, id_product, id_client, date.
```

I want to get a list of all the products that dont belong to a certain client.

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.id, product.title, client.id
FROM product,client
WHERE product.id NOT IN (
SELECT id_product FROM client_has_product WHERE id_client = 1)
GROUP BY product.id
```

Problem is that if the client_has_product table is empty the query returns nothing but if there is even a single line in the client_has_product table the query works.

could somebody please explain what am i missing here and/or why this is happening?

Comment: WHERE id_client) ? the query doesnt look complete

Comment: i fixed it, sorry about that :-)

Comment: use join instead of the subquery and filter for null values

Comment: From what I understand from your problem, you want the record for client and product which are mapped which means, if there are no records in client_has_product, then obviously there will be no output as none are mapped. Or if you want product result even though none client associated then you can use outer join on client to get the result of product except one particular client specified in where clause. So, join these three tables and use where clause to exclude client and make it simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line here is

```
WHERE product.id NOT IN (
SELECT id_product FROM client_has_produc WHERE id_client)
```

Because this will always return false when

```
WHERE product.id NOT IN ( null )
```

Also, this union of tables without an intersection will return a pairing for all rows.

```
FROM product,client
```

And this will always produce one product even if there are 2 or more clients having the same product.

```
GROUP BY product.id
```

The solution would be to do a `join` on all tables, then filter out the specific client.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.id, product.title, client.id
FROM product
LEFT JOIN client_has_produc ON product.id = client_has_produc.id_product
LEFT JOIN client ON client.id = client_has_produc.id_client
WHERE client_has_product.id_client <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace NOT IN WITH JOIN, following is an example:

/*NOT IN query*/

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT ProductID
FROM Production.Product
WHERE ProductID
NOT IN (
SELECT ProductID
FROM Production.WorkOrder);
```

/*JOIN Query*/:-

```
SELECT p.ProductID
FROM Production.Product p
LEFT JOIN Production.WorkOrder w ON p.ProductID = w.ProductID
WHERE w.ProductID IS NULL;
```

Hope that helps!